# How to throttle max thread per route in tomcat/java web server world

Tags: java, multithreading, rest, tomcat, servlet-3.0

let say i have implemented few `Rest` end points.
Now i want to make sure the a particular route let say `POST /log` only get a max of 2 thread and other important route get the rest of the `Threads`.

During load hour we dont want to have many thread out of thread pool invested in `POST /log` route. We dont care about `POST /log` route.

[1] **How to achieve this is in tomcat?**

[2] **Is there some other way to achieve this instead of relaying on web server?**

---

PS: I did find `SingleThreadModel interface in Servlet`, but this has been deprecated.

EDIT:

I dont want to add a filter and *count request and once limit exceed drop the request* as in this case the JVM will still take the heat of switching thread context, just to run my *count request and drop request*.

Ideally something like event loop of `NODE.JS` is refereed where there is only one thread who is processing request and others are queued up.

in my knowledge one crud way to achieve this is by having  different connector for which route and assign threadpool to each.But i looking for something for development friendly.

Comment: By default there is a shared connection pool for all requests. What do you want to do with extra requests in case you allow only 2? Just reject?

Comment: queue till some number and then reject.

Answer (score 2):

Setup the [QoSFilter](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/qos-filter.html) and mark your priorities appropriately for the url-patterns that you want to limit.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is a basic quality of service where you allocate resources to certain URIs.

This can be achieved with Servlet filters, and yes HTTP requests can be queued since Servlet 3.0.

[Jetty](http://eclipse.org/jetty/), for example, provides a QoSFilter exactly for this purpose, see [its documentation](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/qos-filter.html).

Comment: anything similar for tomcat